# Core Data List Entity Names

Tags: iphone, core-data

using Core Data, how would I list (i.e. return an NSArray of NSStrings) all the entity types that I have in my model?

such as Customer, Invoice, etc...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can get the names from the model's entity descriptions:

```
NSArray *entityNames = [[myManagedObjectModel entities] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

or perhaps just:

```
NSArray *entityNames = myManagedObjectModel.entities.name;
```

Answer (score 10):

Swift:

```
let names = persistentContainer.managedObjectModel.entities.map({ (entity) -> String in
    return entity.name!
})
```