# How do I avoid a crash if entity name is wrong in Core Data count/fetch request?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am writing a generic base class for all of my persistence storage classes. Each child class will work with one specific entity/table in a persistent database using Core Data. The threading appears to be working correctly and I can get the count of items in the table correctly. The problem is that if the entity name in the fetch request is wrong, I do not get an exception, I get a crash. Since this is a string and is typed in somewhere in the code by a programmer, I want to detect the error in some better way so that the programmer is alerted to having used an invalid entity name.

Here's my code:

```
class Store<EntityType:NSFetchRequestResult> : NSObject {
    private var entityName : String = ""
    init( entityName : String ) {
        self.entityName = entityName
    }

    public var Count : Int
    {
        get {
            var fetchResults : Int = 0
            objc_sync_enter( self )
            do {

                var privateContext : NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    let deleg = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                    privateContext = deleg.privateManagedObjectContext
                }

                if privateContext == nil
                    { return 0 }

                privateContext!.performAndWait {
                    do
                    {
                        let request = NSFetchRequest<EntityType>( entityName: self.entityName )
                        fetchResults = try privateContext!.count( for: request )
                    } catch
                    {
                        print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
                    }
                }
            }
            objc_sync_exit( self )
            return fetchResults
        }
    }
...
```

With the wrong entity name, the count() function on the MOC causes a SIGABRT and does not throw any exception.

How do I catch the error somehow?

I am also open to comments about the threading and using this in a background thread. It works now but since the internet and Apple all say vague stuff about how to use Core Data in a background thread, help is appreciated.

I also tried this just now:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<EntityType>( entityName: String(reflecting: EntityType.self) )
```

The name is in the form of "app name.entityname" so it might be usable. But since the editor lets the programmer enter a different name for the entity and for the class, this is not at all safe. If I can somehow check at runtime that the name is valid, I'll use this method. But without solving the crash problem, I'm reluctant to change anything right now.

Comment: Xcode stores the entity name as a string in a function call in the class extension it generates from my entity information in the editor. But since it's impossible to create an instance of the entity class without a name ahead of time, I can't get the name from that function somehow. I have to hand it to Apple, they cold have just added a function to return the string name when they create the entity class extension, making all this literal string crap go away. But I guess their programmers like typing in string literals in their code. Ugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to get the list of entity names that exist in the model for the context.

With that, you can check that the entity name supplied by the programmer is valid before executing the fetch request.

```
//get the context and make sure it's not nil
guard let privateContext = privateContext 
else { 
    print("Unexpected error: context is nil.")
    return 0 
}

//get the names of entities in the model associated with this context
// credit: Snowman, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997586/core-data-list-entity-names
guard let names = privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectModel.entities.map({ (entity) -> String? in
    return entity.name
}) 
else { 
    print("Unexpected error: Could not get entity names from model.")
    return 0 
}

//make sure the name specified by the programmer exists in the model    
guard names.contains(where: { (name) -> Bool in
    return name == self.entityName
})
else {
    print("Unexpected error: \(self.entityName) does not exist in the model.")
    return 0 
}

privateContext.performAndWait {
    do 
    {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<EntityType>( entityName: self.entityName )
        fetchResults = try privateContext.count( for: request )
    } catch
    {
        print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
    }
}
```

If you're wondering about performance: in my testing, retrieving the list of entity names 500 times for a model with 20 entities took 20 ms. Nothing to worry about.